# Why am I getting the warning message that NaNs are produced and the error message that function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters?

Tags: r, parameters, curve-fitting, roc

Here is my code.  I'm trying to model an ROC curve using a custom function.  My goal is to estimate the 8 parameters that minimize the sse_total.  However, I keep running into two messages.

The first message is a warning message that tells me NaNs are produced.  The second message is an error message that says the function cannot be evaluated at the initial parameters.

X are non-cumulative false alarm rates, and Y are non-cumulative hit rates.  Non-cumulative are for model estimation only.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
`

```
X<-c(0.01666667,
     0.00000000,
     0.06666667,
     0.11666667,
     0.36666667,
     0.43333333)
Y<-c(0.03333333,
     0.05000000,
     0.06666667,
     0.05000000,
     0.10000000,
     0.70000000)

df_dpsd<-data.frame(x=X,y=Y)

DPSD_1<-function(par){
R<-par[1]
Rn<-par[2]
dprime<-par[3]
c6<-par[4]
c5<-par[5]
c4<-par[6]
c3<-par[7]
c2<-par[8]
# c1<-par[9]

pred_FAR6<-((1-Rn)*qnorm(c6,0,1))
pred_FAR5<-((1-Rn)*(qnorm(c5,0,1)-qnorm(c6,0,1)))
pred_FAR4<-((1-Rn)*(qnorm(c4,0,1)-qnorm(c5,0,1)))
pred_FAR3<-((1-Rn)*(qnorm(c3,0,1)-qnorm(c4,0,1)))
pred_FAR2<-((1-Rn)*(qnorm(c2,0,1)-qnorm(c3,0,1)))
pred_FAR1<-(Rn+(1-Rn)*(1-qnorm(c2,0,1)))

pred_HR6<-(R+(1-R)*qnorm(c6,-dprime,1))
pred_HR5<-((1-R)*(qnorm(c5,-dprime,1)-qnorm(c6,-dprime,1)))
pred_HR4<-((1-R)*(qnorm(c4,-dprime,1)-qnorm(c5,-dprime,1)))
pred_HR3<-((1-R)*(qnorm(c3,-dprime,1)-qnorm(c4,-dprime,1)))
pred_HR2<-((1-R)*(qnorm(c2,-dprime,1)-qnorm(c3,-dprime,1)))
pred_HR1<-((1-R)*(1-qnorm(c2,-dprime,1)))

# SSE
sseH6<-(Y[1]-pred_HR6)^2
sseH5<-(Y[2]-pred_HR5)^2
sseH4<-(Y[3]-pred_HR4)^2
sseH3<-(Y[4]-pred_HR3)^2
sseH2<-(Y[5]-pred_HR2)^2
sseH1<-(Y[6]-pred_HR1)^2

sseF6<-(X[1]-pred_FAR6)^2
sseF5<-(X[2]-pred_FAR5)^2
sseF4<-(X[3]-pred_FAR4)^2
sseF3<-(X[4]-pred_FAR3)^2
sseF2<-(X[5]-pred_FAR2)^2
sseF1<-(X[6]-pred_FAR1)^2

sse_total<-(
  # sseH1+
              sseH2+sseH3+sseH4+sseH5+sseH6+
              # sseF1+
                sseF2+sseF3+sseF4+sseF5+sseF6)
return(sse_total)
}

(result <-optim(par=c(R=.25,Rn=.25,dprime=1,c6=-1.5,c5=-1,c4=-.5,c3=1,c2=1.5),
                fn=DPSD_1))
```

`

I've tried varying the initial parameters and have played around with various ways to configure the function so that it will optimize, but to no avail.

I've also looked through multiple top solutions to similar problems, but I have not had any luck in solving my problem.

Comment: your ```c2```,...,```c6``` are not probability so ```qnorm``` does not work. Replace ```qnorm``` with ```pnorm``` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! 'pnorm' was the way to go!  I appreciate you!